# How can I play video from FTP server to my website?

Tags: ftp, video-streaming, html5-video

I am working on a project where the there is a requirement to play video from ftp server in the website. I am not sure how can I do this, but I am trying. This is a CodeIgniter project. What I am doing is that I am connecting to the ftp server using username and password, fetching the video file names and giving it to the video source which is like doing it for playing video using http protocol. I am not sure how to play the video from the source as it's all ftp link. Also there is authorization. I have done some research on that but I did not find anything useful. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Even if this does work, FTP is incredibly problematic.  It breaks on a lot of NAT routers due to the way it handles ports.  You should be using HTTP instead.  If you can't install a web server on the FTP host, you'll have to proxy it to HTTP.

Comment: I will definitely try to use proxy, for my learning purpose. but I actually use http to solve my problem. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You will not find a workable, cross-platform, secure solution that does not involve the browser accessing these videos via http(s) instead of FTP (say, with nginx or Apache). Also, if you're dealing with FTP and authentication, you will end up exposing the FTP account's password in URLs, which you absolutely do not want to do.  Hope this helps.

Comment: yes I was unable to find any kind of solution that works. So I ended up using http protocol that solved my problem. anyway thanks